# Recreating index on planet_osm_nodes

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

It appears that I have corrupted / overwrote the index planet_osm_nodes for my Open Street Map installation.  I would like to recreate it, but am not sure of the access method (b-tree, GIST...) which osm2pgsql initially created it as.  I am using postgres.

I have tried this:

> create index planet_osm_nodes on public.planet_osm_nodes USING gist (id)

But get errors

Can anyone let me know how best to recreate this index?

Comment: "But get errors"? What exact errors? With a description like this it might be your microwave not ding-ing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The `nodes.id` is a primary key build using the default `btree` index type. (it's from the [code](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/662a48eb2ca382b81b5bfab5608224a94e6ffdfc/middle-pgsql.cpp)).

That being said, if you want to drop/recreate the primary key, you would also have to take note and recreate the foreign keys.